# How protect this link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jwplayer

I want to hide HTML Code from source code, how this is possible?

For example:

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        file: "http://example.com/Media.m3u8",
            autostart: 'true',
            controlbar: 'bottom',
```

`file: "http://example.com/Media.m3u8",`  How can I hide the code?

Comment: If you hide it with php, the code won't be executed.

Comment: If you can view it in the browser then it is as good as pirated...

Comment: @sabof so, Is it not possible to hide?

Comment: if i can hear it, see it, read it. i can steal it

Comment: Not possible to totally hide something. At the end of the day, if people want to take your content badly enough, they will figure out a way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide it, the best you could do is make it a little harder to figure it out.  And this is just obscuring, it is NOT securing.

For the server side portion, you could change:

```
file: "http://example.com/Media.m3u8",
```

to

```
file: window.atob('<?php echo base64_encode("http://example.com/Media.m3u8");?>'),
```

and then the output will be:

```
    file: window.atob('aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL01lZGlhLm0zdTg='),
```

Just know, this won't stop anyone who really wants to figure it out.  It will only stop someone who doesn't know anything about programming and is too lazy to spend five minutes on it.

Comment: You could change for me?
`http://example.com/Media.m3u8`
to
`<?php $var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; print($$var); ?>` -->> `<?php echo base64_encode($var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; print($$var));?>` this is correct?

Comment: `$var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; echo base64_encode($$var);`

Comment: this is equivalent to hiding the door key under the mat

Comment: Thank you but error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in `  --- `<?php echo base64_encode($var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; echo base64_encode($$var););?>`

Comment: And you have base64 encode twice, you only need the last one.
`echo base64_encode($var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; echo base64_encode($$var););?>` should be `$var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_Stream'; echo base64_encode($$var);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It has to be sent to the browser in order to be executed/viewed/played, and the user can always copy it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not handle it, but on the other side, that the link you provided, you can manage the authentication

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to protect the link, you can use some server side code to generate a one time usable link generated each time the page is loaded that only allows access to that file one time. once that use is up the URL is now useless. But even this is able to be bypassed.

Comment: `if you want to spend a ton of money on it you can have a unique URL generated each time the page is loaded` Something like this would be easily possible with some server-side logic, no money needed.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks I changed my wording to make it a more plausible answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to totally hide something. At the end of the day, if people want to take your content badly enough, they will figure out a way to do so.

However, if you want to use HLS AES encryption, or secure streaming via RTMPE, that will help. The JW Player supports both of these. Then you can also use some tools to encode/encrypt/obfuscate your code, however, people with any technical know how can easily decode/decrypt/deobfuscate this with other tools, or simply by using Firebug/Chrome developer tools. It will make it harder for some of your audience to take your videos, though, but not all. But people will still be able to figure out a way to do this if they want your content badly enough, they will even use screen recorders as a last resort. One other thing you should do is encode your videos with your own watermark if you are concerned about people screen recording your videos.

Answer (score -3):

My idea would be to look into only allowing your site (domain name) to download it and encoding the link.